# Trying to improve my code - boolean operations on multiple columns - dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, subset, boolean-expression

I am working on data frames in R , and trying to improve my coding skills.
Here is a data frame I need to subset:

```
testdf<- data.frame(
  col1= c(
    paste("Ga", 1:3, sep = ''),
    paste("Gb", 1:3, sep = ''),
    paste("Gc", 1:3, sep = ''),
    paste("Gb", 1:3, sep = ''),
    paste("Ga", 1:3, sep = '')),
  col2 = c(
    paste("Gb", 4:6, sep = ''),
    paste("Ga", 1:3, sep = ''),
    paste("Ga", 1:3, sep = ''),
    paste("Gc", 1:3, sep = ''),
    paste("Ga", 4:6, sep = '')),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
#
```

Now, I would like to retain only comparisons between "Ga" and "Gb". As you can see, some rows have "Ga" compared to "Gb", some others have the opposite. I would like to keep them either way. Note that there are also within-group comparisons (i.e. Ga vs Ga), which I would like to discard. Also, in the real dataset, the other groups (in this case just "Gc") are many more than the groups I want to keep.

This is my solution:

```
rbind(
  testdf[
    grepl(pattern = "Ga", x = testdf$col1) &
      grepl(pattern = "Gb", x = testdf$col2),],
  testdf[
    grepl(pattern = "Gb", x = testdf$col1) &
      grepl(pattern = "Ga", x = testdf$col2),])
```

I was wondering if there is a cleaner solution, rather than performing two separate operations and then binding them. Not a big deal, but I am trying clean up my act. I look forward to your feedback :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this by subsetting the dataframe once :

```
subset(testdf, grepl('Ga', col1) & grepl('Gb', col2) | 
               grepl('Gb', col1) & grepl('Ga', col2))


#  col1 col2
#1  Ga1  Gb4
#2  Ga2  Gb5
#3  Ga3  Gb6
#4  Gb1  Ga1
#5  Gb2  Ga2
#6  Gb3  Ga3
```

Without using `subset` :

```
testdf[with(testdf, grepl('Ga', col1) & grepl('Gb', col2) | 
                    grepl('Gb', col1) & grepl('Ga', col2)),]
```

---

Using the same logic with `dplyr` and `stringr` :

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

testdf %>%  
   filter(str_detect(col1, 'Ga') & str_detect(col2, 'Gb') | 
          str_detect(col1, 'Gb') & str_detect(col2, 'Ga'))
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I am not a fan of the subset function, which I believe it is still intended for interactive use only, but I like the dplyr/stringr solution 

Comment: @Max_IT Without using `subset` : `testdf[with(testdf, grepl('Ga', col1) & grepl('Gb', col2) | grepl('Gb', col1) & grepl('Ga', col2)),]`

Comment: Nice, thank you. Maybe you could add this last comment to your answer? Just for other users' benefit? 

Comment: Updated the answer :)